# How to fire on change event of select while setting v-model?

Tags: vue.js

I have Dropdown.vue and Sprint.vue use Dropdown.vue

`Dropdown.vue` code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select
      v-model="selected"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      @change="emitChangeEvent"
    >
      <option
        v-for="(option, idx) in options"
        :key="`option-${idx}`"
        :value="option.value"
      >
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Dropdown',
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    value: {
      required: false,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(newValue) {},
    },
  },
  methods: {
    emitChangeEvent() {
      this.$emit('change', this.selected);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In `Sprint.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Dropdown
      v-model="sprint"
      :options="sprints"
      @change="sprintChanged"
    />
    {{ sprint }}

    <button @click="change">
      Change Sprint
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {
  Component, Prop, Vue, Emit,
} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Dropdown from '@/components/Dropdown.vue';

@Component({
  components: {
    Dropdown,
  },
})
export default class Sprint extends Vue {
  private sprint = {};

  private sprints = [
    { text: 'Sprint A', value: 'A' },
    { text: 'Sprint B', value: 'B' },
    { text: 'Sprint C', value: 'C' },
  ];

  change() {
    this.sprint = 'B';
  }

  sprintChanged(value: any) {
    console.log(`value=${value}, sprint=${this.sprint}`);
  }
}
</script>
```

When we select an option, an event was fired. But when I click on the button to set selected option by programming, there is no event of select is fired.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are two main problems in your Dropdown.vue component.

1) You are binding the v-model of the  element to the computed property `selected`, and emitting `selected` in your `emitChangeEvent`

2) and the `selected` computed properties doesn't have a setter so nothing happens when the value change.

To check if this is the only problem, a quick solution is to change your `emitChangeEvent` to this:

```js
emitChangeEvent(event) {
   this.$emit('change', event.target.value);
}
```

Emitting directly the value from event will skip any problem in the definition of the computed property.